# angular 5 if I use angular universal is still necessary to write lazy routes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, angular-universal

I've never used server side HTML rendering, And I am confused if I am using angular universal do I still need to use lazy routes to make my application work faster.

Answer (score 1):

When using server side rendering, the client still loads all of the js code after rendering anyway. So I guess having lazy routes is still a good practice

Comment: Thank you, this is a helpful explanation :)